# Focus on Android

Tags: android, focus, viewgroup

I'd like to implement a Custom View [CV] containing a set of subviews [sv(1)...sv(N)], to be placed in a layout with other views [ev(1)...ev(N)] that has the following behaviour:

- When focus enters [CV] from another view [ev(P)] a default subview
  [sv(D)] of [CV] is set focused.
- should be able to define a focus navigation strategy (up,left,right...) on the subviews [sv(1)...sv(N)].
- should be able to define different views to receive the focus[ev(T)] when focus leaves
  the set of subviews contained in [CV], like sv(1),RIGHT --> ev(3) or
  sv(4),UP -->ev(12)

Now,

1. Where the default focus order is computed: Activity, View or
   Other
2. How to Override it
3. What is exactly the FocusFinder class and how to use it
4. What the method addFocusables of ViewGroup does
       and what is the difference with addChild.
5. Ideally would be optimal for me to manage the focus in a Hierarchical way, based on the hierarchy of Views. Are the methods on ViewGroup class enough to reach this goal? (clearChildFocus, addFocusables, focusSearch, etc.)

Comment: Maybe this can help you. https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, but unfortunately i'm developing on the Android TV and there are no touch gestures, focus became really important on devices controlled with a remote.

Comment: Then check the ViewGroup documentation on Android Dev. There are some methods to get the focused child views from ViewGroup like android:descendantFocusability: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:descendantFocusability. There are also some flags to force the view to get the focus only if none of their childs are focused

Comment: I'm currently struggling with focus on Android TV, did you find anything useful?

Comment: Hey @AndrewBloom: Did you find a solution to this? I'm doing something similar & am stuck at the same issue

Comment: No, I didn't find a solution to this and i think i bypassed the problem using another strategy. That was for a project long time ago, so i don't remember the actual details now.